# Editing max_brightness

Tags: screen, brightness

Is it possible to edit the value in `/sys/class/brightness/acpi_video0/max_brightness/` ?

I've tried: `sudo echo 16 > max_brightness` from the directory, but I'm getting `Permission Denied`

The current value is `15`. Is this the actual hardware limit? Or is this what Ubuntu believes to be the limit.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that you can do that.

To adjust brightness in ubuntu Open a terminal window, and execute this command to edit **/etc/rc.local**

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add this before the last line “exit 0″:

```
echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

number 10 is the value of your screen brightness of your choice, range from 1 to 10 or 15. With this command check the maximum:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

[source](http://www.namhuy.net/528/adjust-brightness-in-xubuntu.html)

And also one more way we have to do this is with another new program named as **xbacklight** open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then type this `xbacklight -set 100`

there 100 stands for brightness range we can get it upto 100 from 0 .

But i didn't try it.